# Burst pressure of a sphere

Tags: pressure, statics, stresses, pressure-vessel

Is there a formula for the burst working pressure of a spherical pressure vessel that takes into account its material peoperties? It should be noted that this is not a concentric sphere design (it has only one radius) .This is a formula for a pipe: http://www.engineersedge.com/calculators/pipe_bust_calc.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For spheres,stresses in the material  is same in all directions.So ,hoop stress and longitudinal stresses are the same. 
Using similar abbreviations, as P for pressure(gauge) inside sphere ,FS for factor of safety,S for allowable stress and additionly
Ri for inner radius,Ro for outer radius
        P(gauge pressure)=((Ro^2-Ri^2)×S)÷((Ri^2)×FS)
For calculation of brusting pressure,take S as ultimate 
stress for a given material and put FS=1

Comment: What if the sphere is nonconcentric (as in it has only one radius)?

Comment: Use the thickness of the thinnest section as a first approximation